# How can I using GitLab CI with codequality?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

Recently I am study using Gitlab CI. As a demo ,I decided to configure a code quality check job. After regist runner, I config my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file like this:

```
code_quality:
  image: docker:stable
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  allow_failure: true
  services:
    - docker:stable-dind
  script:
    - export SP_VERSION=$(echo "$CI_SERVER_VERSION" | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\).*/\1-\2-stable/')
    - docker run
        --env SOURCE_CODE="$PWD"
        --volume "$PWD":/code
        --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/codequality:$SP_VERSION" /code
  artifacts:
    reports:
      codequality: gl-code-quality-report.json
```

This is the official webpage: [Link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/code_quality.html)

This is a template from gitlab official. And when I run the pipline, it just like jammed. Then I knew, the docker is pulling a lot of `codeclimate` images, include two over 1GB images. And finally, it cost about 15 minutes to pull this images.

It's cost too much time to me, so I think I could make a local registry to let pulling speed up (Because it use docker in docker tech, so everytime I run pipline there is a containerA and run a containerB in containerA. So for containerA， there is never have local image. So containerA always pull images from registry.) After I deploy a local registry on my server, and push all 10GB+ images to it. I changed my `.gitlab-ci.yml` like this:

```
code_quality:
  image: docker:latest
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  before_script:
    - which docker
  allow_failure: true
  services:
    - name: docker:stable-dind
      command: ["--insecure-registry=192.168.0.1:5000"]
  script:
    - which docker
    - docker pull 192.168.0.1:5000/codeclimate:0.72.0
    - docker pull 192.168.0.1:5000/codeclimate-structure:latest
    - docker pull 192.168.0.1:5000/codeclimate-duplication:latest
    - docker pull 192.168.0.1:5000/codeclimate-coffeelint:latest
    - docker pull 192.168.0.1:5000/codeclimate-csslint:latest
    - docker pull 192.168.0.1:5000/codeclimate-eslint:latest
    - docker pull 192.168.0.1:5000/codeclimate-rubocop:latest
    - docker pull 192.168.0.1:5000/codeclimate-fixme:latest
    - export SP_VERSION=$(echo "$CI_SERVER_VERSION" | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\).*/\1-\2-stable/')
    - docker run
        --env SOURCE_CODE="$PWD"
        --env CODECLIMATE_VERSION=0.72.0
        --env TIMEOUT_SECONDS=90
        --volume "$PWD":/code
        --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        192.168.0.1:5000/codequality:latest /code
  artifacts:
    reports:
      codequality: gl-code-quality-report.json
```

(The 192.168.0.1 is localhost)

And I ran pipline again, it even slower than pulling image from Internet! By executed command `iostat`, my harddisk io speed just over 1740kb/s, and it cost

It make me felling lose. Do you have any advice? 
Thank you guys!

Comment: If the gitlab-runner already pulled the image it will reuse it if possible, so using upstream registry should be enough.

Also, keep in mind code quality requires EE.

Answer (score 0):

It is slow when my gitlab-runner server is a virtual machin. When I using a real server, docker pulled all images with in a second!